# How to click an element with Selenium Basic using VBA?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the table button but I'm having trouble.

Here is the HTML

Tablo

And the Xpath

/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span/button[2]

I tried the following didn't work.

tarihsel. FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span/button[2]").Click

Comment: What's not working? What error message are you getting? Have you tried other xpaths or other element locators (CSS locator, ID, class, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `Click` method on the WebElement object returned by the `FindElementByXPath` method, like this:

```
tarihsel.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/span/button[2]").Click
```

Make sure that you have correctly referenced the Selenium library and imported the necessary modules.